# LPVOID not recognized in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to use the following code to convert a native string to a managed string in C++\CLI:

```
System::String^ NativeToDotNet( const std::string& input )
{
    return System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi( (static_cast<LPVOID>)( input.c_str() ) );
}
```

I originally found the code [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.531998.4):

But when I try to build it throws the error:

```
syntax error : identifier 'LPVOID'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crops up quite often in various guises - the simplest answer is: don't write your own function, see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Comment: adding on to above answer


#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(m_nativeClassPtr->getSomeString());

Answer (score 1):

LPVOID is just an alias for void *.  LP stands for "long pointer," which is an old-style way of saying "machine-sized pointer", either 32 or 64 bit depending on the process.

Just use 
`static_cast<void *>`

In one or more header files somewhere, there's a
`#define LPVOID (void *)`

You haven't included such a file.

Comment: That gives errors with: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'void *'

Comment: @Adam: ...which is quite reasonable. Any time you have a `void *`, you can expect to have to cast it to some other kind of pointer to do anything useful with it.

Comment: You need to cast to <const void *>, or cast the const away by using const_cast<char *>.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to (same *cv-qualifiers*) `void*` is always implicitly possible, you should never see a cast trying to do so.  The error is from trying to remove `const` with a `static_cast`

Try this, which also handles embedded NUL characters correctly:

```
using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi;
return PtrToStringAnsi( const_cast<char*>(&input[0]), input.size() );
```

The `const_cast<char*>` takes care of the stupidity which is the lack of const-correctness in .NET